# Flutter device orientation not detected after rotation lock disabled

Tags: android, ios, flutter, orientation

I'm having an issue on both iOS and Android with unlocking device rotation.

If device rotation is unlocked before the app starts, the app switches between portrait and landscape perfectly, no problems.

However, if it begins locked, then I unlock rotation on the device, I need to back out of a page and go back in for orientation changes to be detected.

Has anybody else had this issue?